# What keyboard shortcut opens the Windows 10 Action Center?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

In Windows 8 I could use `WinKey+C` to open the Charms. Since the Action Center is at the same location in the operating system, I would assume `WinKey+C` would open it. But `WinKey+C` opens Cortana in Windows 10. What opens the Action Center in Windows 10?

Answer (score 19):

To open the Windows 10 Action Center, use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

Comment: What if that doesn't do anything? (build 1809 in case that matters)

Comment: This hotkey no longer works...

Answer (score 1):

Tapping the touchpad with 4 fingers on my Toshiba laptop with Elan drivers also works.

Comment: I was trying to figure out why the $#@$ Action Center kept opening, so your response helped me.

Comment: Thanks. It's not a keyboard shortcut technically but it definitely gets the job done!